# Dificuldade em criar autenticação customizada - laravel

Tags: laravel

Preciso criar um sistema de autenticação em três niveis: user, therapist e student.
A principio tenho uma unica tabela, mas penso em criar 3 tabelas diferentes.
o problema é: como e onde faço para procurar o email do usuário em tabelas diferentes?

Comment: Porque 3 tabelas? Tem campos diferentes esses tipos? Sua pergunta é ampla

Comment: Olá Virgilio, sim cada um deles possui um campo que os difere.

Comment: Então acrescente esse campo no User Model e isso vai resolver seu problema